# Any way to "Detach" part of a dialog?

Tags: mfc, dialog, controls, cdialog

I am working on an old CDialog based application which uses Codejock [XTP](http://www.codejock.com/products/toolkitpro/).
On this dialog, I have a separate [TaskPanel](http://www.codejock.com/products/taskpanel/) on the right edge of the Dialog.
(I can't post images yet, not enough reputation)

I want to provide a way for the user to be able to Detach/Attach the taskpanel from the dialog. So if the panel is detached, the user can move the main dialog and the now detached "Tasks" dialog individually (maybe on multiple monitors). If attached, the panel is part of the main dialog only.

There are a lot of controls on the panel which I want to try and separate. Most of the controls modify multiple controls which may or may not be part of the tasks panel (so assuming I create a new Dialog, may be part of any of the two dialogs).

What approach should I follow to separate and un-separate the panel? I think it is inevitable that I would have to create a new dialog for that separated panel. I need to consider that the controls may have changed values and states which I will need to keep in sync. Also, the current handlers for the controls might be referring to other controls, assuming they are on the same dialog. There are a lot of controls so changing this will require a lot of work.

Can anyone suggest any resources/samples or anything which may be helpful?

Comment: Is it a modal dialog?

Comment: Yes, the original dialog is modal. I am not sure if the new detached dialog needs to be modal.

Comment: Good luck. (More seriously I think you have a design problem here. Can you think of any mainstream programs that allow such a thing? On a technical level the modal dialog will intercept all messages so placing the control on another window will be hard.)